# SSL for dummies

Tags: c#, iphone, security, ssl

I want to add some security to a client(iPhone) - server(c#) application I'm working on, mainly to encrypt messages sent between client and server.
I know i should use SSL but not really sure what the steps i need to do in both client and server to implement it.
Can someone please give me some guidance?

I don't use HTTP protocol, i use my own textual protocol, but any way with HTTP or my own protocol how do i add ssl support? i know that in c# there is SSLStream instead of regular Stream. And on ios there is some stream settings i need to configure, i just don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Take the easy approach, which is allowed to go on the App Store without having to go through all the encryption law stuff. Simply use a HTTP server and a client.

C# runs the HTTP server (maybe use IIS to handle that? Maybe C# has its own software for that) and the iPhone simply uses `NSURLRequest`.

Easy to implement and safe, since you'll benefit from patches from Apple and Microsoft.

**Update for the updated question**: I did some quick research and this kept popping up: `kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings` - maybe it helps you. It's apparently something for NSStream that allows it to create SSL connections, or something. I'm afraid I can't help you more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Host the application using SSL in IIS, then use HTTPS as the service point. [edit] Don't forget you'll need a cert.

Comment: Can u explain about the certificate? i heard there is self sign certificate i can use for free, is that good enough?